# yii2 advanced app search model not executing first where condition

Tags: php, search, yii2

i have a search model where i need to get only active models (status 1) without deleted models (status 0) but it is showing all models including deleted ones
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

```
public function search($params) 
$query = Post::find()->where(['status' => 1]);

$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'created_at' => SORT_DESC,
            'title' => SORT_ASC, 
        ]
    ],
]);

// returns an array of Post objects
$posts = $provider->getModels();
```

This code do not execute the first condition `where(['status' => 1])`

why?

Comment: I don't see any problem in code you've posted. But in the title you mention "first where" do you have multiple `where()` method calls before calling `$provider->getModels()`?

Comment: no! the first where means: where(['status' => 1]) after that i have andwhere but i removed them to see if it is working. but it's not